# Is there a risk in using @Html.Raw?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a risk in using `@Html.Raw`? It seems to me there shouldn't be. If there is a risk then wouldn't that risk already exist regardless of using `@Html.Raw` in that modern browsers such as Chrome will allow an edit injection of `<script>malicious()</script>` or even to change a form's post action to something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Html.Raw` will allow executing any script that is on the value to display. If you want to prevent that you need to use `@Html.AttributeEncode`

Answer (score 4):

Correct, the risk is in how it is used. There's no risk inherent in `Html.Raw`. It's a tool, nothing more.

Comment: And the same can be said about mustard. Or mustard gas.

Answer (score 4):

If you are displaying user entered information it is better to use @Html.Encode().

In another words, if you are `displaying non-user eneterd data` you are safe to go with @Html.Raw()

Comment: This is a good point, and I completely agree :) But my usage is intended to output an input box from an html helper so I think I will be safe.