# ASP.Net MVC - How to display string from view model inside html tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
<span class="text-danger">
@{
    if (Model.uploadErrorMessage != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.uploadErrorMessage))
        {
            Model.uploadErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
</span>
```

Given code above, how do I display `Model.uploadErrorMessage` inside `<span>` tag?

Currently it give me this error on `Model.uploadErrorMessage`:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Use `<text>Html.Raw(Model.uploadErrorMessage)</text>` or just `<text>@Model.uploadErrorMessage</text>`.

Comment: `<span>@Model.uploadErrorMessage</span>`

Comment: The outer `if` statement is made redundant by the inner one, and you can remove them both anyway - see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your span tag inside if statement

```
@{
    if (Model.uploadErrorMessage != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.uploadErrorMessage))
        {
            <span class="text-danger">@Model.uploadErrorMessage</span>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All of those `if` statements are completely unnecessary anyway, you can simplify the entire thing to this:

```
<span class="text-danger">@Model.uploadErrorMessage</span>
```

Comment: I may put at least one `if` that embrace the span and not adding an empty DOM to the page when the message is null or empty:-)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Well yes, around the `span` would be different, but it's possible the empty span is required due to some Javascript thing perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

use the "@"-symbol to write your variable value to the view:

for example:

```
<span>This is the error: @(Model.uploadErrorMessage)</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>`@Html.Raw(Model.uploadErrorMessage)`</s>

you can simply put `@Model.uploadErrorMessage`

> Edit: XSS vulnerability fix, based on @DavidG's comment.

Comment: That's a bit dangerous though, would absolutely not recommend doing it that way. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144943/is-there-a-risk-in-using-html-raw

Comment: thanks @DavidG, would you mind elaborating a bit on `That's a bit dangerous`

Comment: Yes, see the link I gave, and here http://kevinchalet.com/2018/01/09/why-you-should-never-use-html-raw-in-your-razor-views/

Comment: Well now your answer is the same as the existing one, and the big "edit" banner is not needed.

Comment: yeah, that'll help others

Comment: How will it help beyond the other answers though? It's just duplicate content.

Comment: I meant the "edit" banner, but I got the context, many thanks once again