# Javascript converts XML characters to &LT and &GT

Tags: javascript, xml, asp.net-mvc, dymo

I am currently using DYMO Label Printing software to print labels. I have previously had the label XML template stored as plain text and it worked fine. But recently I have decided to move to a more dynamic approach so that labels can be edited and modified directly from the database.

So I am currently storing the XML label templates in a simple SQL database table. I set up the viewmodel that contains the XML information, and then access it in Javascript when printing in the View itself.

I previously just tried this:

```
        try {

            var labelXml = "@Viewmodel.XMLString"; //Open XML from Viewmodel directly
            var labelD = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);                        
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert("Couldn't load label");
            return;
        }
```

And that did not work.

I did some research and also tried this (placing viewmodel in "text/plain") and then accessing it above.

```
    <script>
           try {

            var labelXml = $('#label_XML').text();
            var labelD = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);                             
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert("Couldn't load label");
            return;
        }     
   

</script>

<script id="label_XML" type="text/plain">
    @Viewmodel.XML
</script>
```

***Both of these methods result in this: (<> replaced with &lt and &gt)***
[image: XML rendered in Source]

How can I simply access a XML string in the database from the viewmodel while avoiding any unwanted conversions? Thanks.

Using @Html.Raw results in this problem:

[image]

The first line is read correctly but with each line break it reads as code instead of text. I put the original @Html.Raw in quotes, is there a way to prevent it from attempting to read it as code as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are struggling with HTML Encoding. Have you tried using `@Html.Raw(Viewmodel.XML)`? That helper should prevent MVC from HTML encoding the content.

Depending on where that XML content comes from, you might be creating an XSS risk, so be careful how you use Html.Raw and consider reading more about it if it does solve this problem for you [Is there a risk in using @Html.Raw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144943/is-there-a-risk-in-using-html-raw)

Comment: This worked to a certain extent. I used Html.Raw, but now on each line break it reads the XML as code, even when I put the Html.Raw in quotes. How can I read the entire XML string as pure text? I included a screenshot above.

Comment: Can you try this wrapping the call with backticks? I'm not sure if this will format correctly here...  `\`@Html.Raw(ViewModel.XML)\``
This piece of the puzzle is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: I awarded you the answer, still have a couple minor things to figure out but using @Html.Raw with backticks did fix almost all issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I ended up using a completely different solution for this issue. I used JSON AJAX to insert the XML directly from a controller action and it worked well. If anyone runs into this same issue check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73774517/html-raw-with-xml-string)