# @Html.raw with XML string

Tags: html, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am pulling an XML template from the database and then using this template in my view (DYMO labels).

My issue is that when I use @Html.Raw, even with quotes around it, it only reads the first line as "Text" and after the line break reads the rest of the XML file as code on the page.

Picture below:

[[image]1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJj5f.png)

The first line appears fine, but starting with <DesktopLabel Version the XML is rendered as not plain text inside quotes.

Here is my current behind the scenes code:

```
            var labelXml = '@Html.Raw(Model.XML)';
```

I need the entirety of the string stored in quotes ("", ''). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using a JSON AJAX controller action call. Code and explanation below in case anyone ever needs help on this:

```
  try {
            var _size = "@Model.size";         
            $.ajax({
                data: { size: _size},
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Unit/GetXMLFile/",
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    var labelD = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(data);
                    labelD.print(printerName);                


                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("error" + response.responseText);
                }
            });  

        }
        catch(err) {
            alert("Couldn't load label");
            return;
        }
```

Because we are directly injecting the XML string into our DYMO framework we prevent any chance of encoding the <> characters as &lt and &gt.

I believe that the root issue came from attempting to transfer XML strings from Viewmodel > Javascript. Even attempting to store the XML in the viewmodel and store as plain text once inside the view did not work.

The only method that worked was the AJAX direct controller action that keeps XMLs format without any conversion.

Here is my controller action:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetXMLFile(string size)
    {
        string XML = "";
        if (size == "Small")
        {
            XML = db.UnitLabels.Where(x => x.Size == "Small").Select(x => x.LabelXML).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            XML = db.UnitLabels.Where(x => x.Size == "Large").Select(x => x.LabelXML).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return Json(XML, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode the xml

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.XML))
```

Comment: This modifies my XML text and changes <> to &lt and &gt.